# Best way to do a PHP switch with multiple values per case?

Tags: php, switch-statement

How would you do this PHP switch statement?

Also note that these are much smaller versions, the one I need to create will have a lot more values added to it.

Version 1:

```
switch ($p) { 
    case 'home': 
    case '': 
        $current_home = 'current';
    break; 
    
    case 'users.online': 
    case 'users.location': 
    case 'users.featured': 
    case 'users.new': 
    case 'users.browse': 
    case 'users.search': 
    case 'users.staff': 
        $current_users = 'current';
    break;
     
    case 'forum': 
        $current_forum = 'current';
    break; 
}
```

Version 2:

```
switch ($p) { 
    case 'home': 
        $current_home = 'current';
    break; 
    
    case 'users.online' || 'users.location' || 'users.featured' || 'users.browse' || 'users.search' || 'users.staff': 
        $current_users = 'current';
    break;
    
    case 'forum': 
        $current_forum = 'current';
    break; 
}
```

**Test Results**:

I ran some speed test on 10,000 iterations,

Time 1: 0.0199389457703 // If statements
Time 2: 0.0389049446106 //switch statements
Time 3: 0.106977939606 // Arrays

Comment: Version 2 doesn't do what you think.

Comment: version 2 doesn't work, read here for more info: http://www.nutt.net/2004/12/28/multiple-cases-for-switch-construct/

Comment: @jasondavis If you use variable variables you'll have a code that SMALL AND SIMPLE, just the way I like it =) Check out my answer, it's tested and works.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For any situation where you have an unknown string and you need to figure out which of a bunch of *other* strings it matches up to, the only solution which doesn't get slower as you add more items is to use an array, but have all the possible strings as keys. So your switch can be replaced with the following:

```
// used for $current_home = 'current';
$group1 = array(
        'home'  => True,
        );

// used for $current_users = 'current';
$group2 = array(
        'users.online'      => True,
        'users.location'    => True,
        'users.featured'    => True,
        'users.new'         => True,
        'users.browse'      => True,
        'users.search'      => True,
        'users.staff'       => True,
        );

// used for $current_forum = 'current';
$group3 = array(
        'forum'     => True,
        );

if(isset($group1[$p]))
    $current_home = 'current';
else if(isset($group2[$p]))
    $current_users = 'current';
else if(isset($group3[$p]))
    $current_forum = 'current';
else
    user_error("\$p is invalid", E_USER_ERROR);
```

This doesn't look as clean as a `switch()`, but it is the only *fast* solution which doesn't include writing a small library of functions and classes to keep it tidy. It is still very easy to add items to the arrays.

Comment: to be technically correct, this gets slower as you add more items, it just gets slower much more slowly - hash tables are blazingly fast but they aren't magic :-)

Answer (score 31):

#### Version 2 does not work!!

```
case 'users.online' || 'users.location' || ...
```

is exactly the same as:

```
case True:
```

and that `case` will be chosen for any value of `$p`, unless `$p` is the empty string.

`||` Does not have any special meaning inside a `case` statement, you are not comparing `$p` to each of those strings, you are just checking to see if it's not `False`.

Comment: ok, would you think that using a switch or if statement is faster then creating multiple arrays and checking if a value is in an array multiple times?

Comment: I have never heard or read anything that makes me think a switch() would be faster. An route is still going to do a whole heap of string comparisons.

Comment: here is something that shows an array may be slower http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324665/which-is-faster-inarray-or-a-bunch-of-expressions-in-php

Answer (score 8):

Put those many values into an array and query the array, as the switch-case seems to hide the underlying semantics of what you're trying to achieve when a string variable is used as the condition, making it harder to read and understand, e.g.:

```
$current_home = null;
$current_users = null;
$current_forum = null;

$lotsOfStrings = array('users.online', 'users.location', 'users.featured', 'users.new');

if(empty($p)) {
    $current_home = 'current';
}

if(in_array($p,$lotsOfStrings)) {
    $current_users = 'current';
}

if(0 === strcmp('forum',$p)) {
    $current_forum = 'current';
}
```

Comment: +1 The first time I read the question, this solution came to mind first. As the number of cases increase, all you need to do is add values to the array and rely on the in_array to do it's job.

Comment: in my case to do it this way, I would have many different arrays so I would be doing the in_array against several arrays, do you think there is any performance gain in 1 way vs another?

Comment: I haven't tried benchmarking it it's easier to read, especially it you'll use constants. How many different arrays (and sizes) are you expecting to use?

Comment: I don't think there will be any perceptible difference in performance. Even if there was, I would probably still stick with the above because it just makes more sense to me in terms of readability and maintainability.

Comment: @Randell this is used for a menu selector on a hgih traffic site so there will only be about 8 arrays and some of them can be up to about 15 items each, I know it's not BIG but it is extra work being done and there is going to be a lot of traffic and this would be something that is done on every single page load.  Thats why I am asking

Comment: @jasondavis - That should be nothing to worry about at all. You can always use microtime() to compare the performance, but I still think the difference would be negligible or nothing to worry about.

Comment: just for knowledge, here is a similar test I found, in this case it seems in_array might be slower then I had thought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324665/which-is-faster-inarray-or-a-bunch-of-expressions-in-php

Comment: I'm assuming that in_array is using hash behind the scene so it's still faster than checking the cases one by one.  And again, it's more readable. You might also want to check the design of your menu. I'm wondering why there are 8 arrays. In any case,i'll go with karim79's answer.

Comment: Whoa! I didn't expect that. The difference is negligible. You don't want to sacrifice code readability for that.

Comment: If performance is really an issue here (see numerous posts about the danger of optimizing too soon), and the look up tables really big enough to worry about the speed of in_array, then a properly indexed database is the right solution. Not to be considered until you KNOW you need to optimize.

Comment: `in_array` will not perform well for large arrays, because there is no hash of *values* in an array, so it has to loop over each item in the array until it finds a match (or runs out of items). There is also some overhead in allocating the array holding the list of matches in the first place, as opposed to the compiled-in tests in a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of completeness, I'll point out that the broken "Version 2" logic can be replaced with a switch statement that works, and *also* make use of arrays for both speed and clarity, like so:

```php
// used for $current_home = 'current';
$home_group = array(
    'home'  => True,
);

// used for $current_users = 'current';
$user_group = array(
    'users.online'      => True,
    'users.location'    => True,
    'users.featured'    => True,
    'users.new'         => True,
    'users.browse'      => True,
    'users.search'      => True,
    'users.staff'       => True,
);

// used for $current_forum = 'current';
$forum_group = array(
    'forum'     => True,
);

switch (true) {
    case isset($home_group[$p]):
        $current_home = 'current';
        break;
    case isset($user_group[$p]):
        $current_users = 'current';
        break;
    case isset($forum_group[$p]):
        $current_forum = 'current';
        break;
    default:
        user_error("\$p is invalid", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays you can do...

```
switch ([$group1, $group2]){
    case ["users", "location"]:
    case ["users", "online"]:
        Ju_le_do_the_thing();
        break;
    case ["forum", $group2]:
        Foo_the_bar();
        break;
}
```

Here's a ready ready-to-run set of code demonstrating the concept:

```
<?php

function show_off_array_switch(){
  $first_array = ["users", "forum", "StubbornSoda"];
  $second_array = ["location", "online", "DownWithPepsiAndCoke"];

  $rand1 = array_rand($first_array);
  $rand2 = array_rand($second_array);

  $group1 = $first_array[$rand1];
  $group2 = $second_array[$rand2];

  switch ([$group1, $group2]){
      case ["users", "location"]:
      case ["users", "online"]:
          echo "Users and Online";
          break;
      case ["forum", $group2]:
          echo "Forum and variable";
          break;
      default:
          echo "default";
  }
  echo "\nThe above result was generated using the array: \n" . print_r([$group1, $group2], true);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
  show_off_array_switch();
}
```

The following has (for one random run) output the following:

```
 Users and Online
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => users
    [1] => online
)
Users and Online
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => users
    [1] => online
)
default
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => users
    [1] => DownWithPepsiAndCoke
)
Users and Online
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => users
    [1] => location
)
Forum and variable
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => forum
    [1] => DownWithPepsiAndCoke
)
Forum and variable
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => forum
    [1] => DownWithPepsiAndCoke
)
Forum and variable
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => forum
    [1] => online
)
default
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => StubbornSoda
    [1] => location
)
Users and Online
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => users
    [1] => location
)
Users and Online
The above result was generated using the array: 
Array
(
    [0] => users
    [1] => location
)
```

Comment: did anyone test this ?

Comment: I have, and just to be sure, I just now checked it again. Still works well!

Comment: @Tanzeel For you, just added a fully runnable code example to show that it works.

Answer (score 5):

Some other ideas not mentioned yet:

```
switch(true){ 
  case in_array($p, array('home', '')): 
    $current_home = 'current'; break;

  case preg_match('/^users\.(online|location|featured|new|browse|search|staff)$/', $p):
    $current_users = 'current'; break;

  case 'forum' == $p:
    $current_forum = 'current'; break; 
}
```

Someone will probably complain about readability issues with #2, but I would have no problem inheriting code like that.

Comment: Funny, a buddy of mine just sent me very similar code saying it works and I immediately came to Stack Overflow to see if anyone else had thought of this as a solution. I think it's pretty cool

Comment: Even if you think it is "cool" this verbose version of an if-elseif-elseif block removes the only advantage that a `switch` can provide because `switch(true)` means that cases must be evaluated.  Conversely, the whole point of using a `switch()` is to evaluate a condition only once and find the static case that satisfies it.

Answer (score 4):

If *anyone* else was ever to maintain your code, they would almost certainly do a double take on version 2 -- that's extremely non-standard.

I would stick with version 1.  I'm of the school of though that case statements without a statement block of their own should have an explicit `// fall through` comment next to them to indicate it is indeed your intent to fall through, thereby removing any ambiguity of whether you were going to handle the cases differently and forgot or something.

Answer (score 3):

Version 1 is certainly easier on the eyes, clearer as to your intentions, and easier to add case-conditions to.

I've never tried the second version. In many languages, this wouldn't even compile because each case labels has to evaluate to a constant-expression.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely prefer Version 1. Version 2 may require less lines of code, but it will be extremely hard to read once you have a lot of values in there like you're predicting.

(Honestly, I didn't even know Version 2 was legal until now. I've never seen it done that way before.)

Answer (score 1):

No version 2 doesn't actually work but if you want this kind of approach you can do the following (probably not the speediest, but arguably more intuitive):

`switch (true) {

  case ($var === 'something' || $var === 'something else'):

    // do some stuff

  break;

}`

Comment: Not intuitive at all. This could be replaced by a simple `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think version 1 is the way to go. It is a lot easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( in_array( $test, $array1 ) )
{
    // do this
}
else if( stristr( $test, 'commonpart' ) )
{
    // do this
}
else
{
    switch( $test )
    {
        case 1:
            // do this
            break;
        case 2:
            // do this
            break;
        default:
            // do this
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch in combination with **[variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)** will give you more flexibility:

```
<?php
$p = 'home'; //For testing

$p = ( strpos($p, 'users') !== false? 'users': $p);
switch ($p) { 
    default:
        $varContainer = 'current_' . $p; //Stores the variable [$current_"xyORz"] into $varContainer
        ${$varContainer} = 'current'; //Sets the VALUE of [$current_"xyORz"] to 'current'
    break;

}
//For testing
echo $current_home;
?>
```

To learn more, checkout [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and the examples I submitted to php manual:

**Example 1**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#105293

**Example 2**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#105282

PS: This example code is **SMALL AND SIMPLE**, just the way I like it. It's tested and works too

Comment: OP is asking how to, in general, combine multiple `case` conditions most efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
        switch ($variable) {
        case 0:
            exit;
            break;
        case (1 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6):
            die(var_dump('expression'));
        default:
            die(var_dump('default'));
            # code...
            break;
    }
```

Comment: better if you make some explanation your answer and re-formatted your code

Comment: `1 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6` will always result in `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply looking for common patterns in strings.  I would have thought a regular expression would be a more efficient way of doing this as PHP implements this with preg_match so little code to write and probably massively quicker.  For example:

```
case preg_match('/^users./'):
// do something here
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP documentation you can do that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php#41767

```php
$input = 'users.online';
$checked = null;
        
switch (true):
    case ($input === 'home'):
        $checked = 'ok 1';
        break;

    case (in_array($input , ['users.online', 'users.location', 'users.featured', 'users.browse', 'users.search', 'users.staff'])):
        $checked = 'ok 2';
        break;

    case ($input === 'forum'):
        $checked = 'ok 3';
        break;
endswitch;

echo $checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be Version 2:

```
if (in_array($p,['users.online','users.location','users.featured','users.browse','users.search','users.staff'])){
$p="users";
}
switch ($p) { 
    case 'home': 
        $current_home = 'current';
    break;
    case 'users': 
        $current_users = 'current';
    break;
    case 'forum': 
        $current_forum = 'current';
    break; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this and it works

```
switch ($variable) {
    case 0:
        exit;
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        die(var_dump('expression'));
    default:
        die(var_dump('default'));
        # code...
        break;
}
```

Case 1,2 and three will execute same piece of code.