# PHP switch case two variables in the case

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have an array that holds the `group_id_status` values `0`, `1`

`$_POST['id']` gives me the values of the selected checkboxes as an array like this : `132,133,134`

i gives array

```php
$array_id_status = array(
    $value => $customers->group_id_status
);
```

when i set var_dump , gived to me this

```php
array(1) { [134]=> string(1) "0" } array(1) { [133]=> string(1) "0" } array(1) { [132]=> string(1) "1" }**
```

now i want show some message to user from switch case

like this when each checkboxes is selected

```
switch ($array_id_status)
{
    case ($array_id_status[$value] == 0 && $array_id_status[$value] == 1):
    echo "Different values are selected";
    case ($array_id_status[$value] == 1):
    echo "Can not change";
    case ($array_id_status[$value] == 0):
    echo "generated GROUP ID 1";
}
```

Comment: You'd have to use `switch(true)` then, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21923957/1427878 - which is generally considered rather dirty. Actually, for such a limited case, I would probably forgo the switch completely, and go with if/else.

Comment: `($array_id_status[$value] == 0 && $array_id_status[$value] == 1)` - that condition can't be fulfilled to begin with. The same variable can not have two different values at the same time.

Comment: I used the if / else case before but I did not get the result I wanted

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `&&` in a case of a `switch` statement in PHP. You can only specify a *single value* or expression in each case statement.
if you need to test multiple conditions, you can use `if` statements.
For example:

```
if (in_array(0, $array_id_status) && in_array(1, $array_id_status)) 
{
    echo "Different values are selected";
} 
else if (in_array(1, $array_id_status)) 
{
    echo "Can not change";
} 
else if (in_array(0, $array_id_status)) 
{
    echo "generated GROUP ID 1";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use foreach with $array_id_status and switch case inside

Comment: Can you give me an example?