# What's the most concise way to check if a variable matches one of a range of values in PHP?

Tags: php, comparison

I'm currently using this for a nav list to highlight the active page:

```
<?= ($current_page == 'thema_list' ? 'class="on"' : '') ?>
```

Extending this to check another page would be:

```
<?= ($current_page == 'thema_list' || $current_page == 'thema_edit' ? 'class="on"' : '') ?>
```

Is there a way to avoid this repetition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2 values, this is probably the fastest method for the amount of time it takes PHP to process it, but you can use in_array if you have a lot of values:

```
<?= (in_array($current_page, array('thema_list', 'thema_edit')) ? 'class="on"' : '') ?>
```

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324665/which-is-faster-inarray-or-a-bunch-of-expressions-in-php) regarding some speed tests related to in_array vs just checking for each value individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with `in_array()`

```
$matches = array("thema_list", "thema_edit", "thema_other");
if (in_array($current_page, $matches)) {
    echo 'class="on"'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could you put them in an array and then use:

```
if(in_array($current_page, $array_values))
{
    echo 'class on';
}
```