# Is there a more efficient way to find an element in an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have to retrieve daily more than thousands of records of an international database, but I have to compare each of one of those with my database in order to avoid registering duplicated records in my database. Actually I'm using the function

```
in_array($element,$myarray)
```

So I'm looking for a more efficient way to verify whether a element is already in my array or not.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you just use unique constraint in the database?

Comment: Well, you could build a hash with these array elements serving as keys; then you'll just have to check for `isset($hash[$some_element])` ... But as @Esailija said, the optimal solution is to introduce this constraint on another, more appropriate level.

Comment: Looks like you might need [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two arrays and use `array_diff`.

`array_diff` will give you an array in return containing the values that differ.

See more in [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the fasest way to handle this. The only other couple of ways is iterating through the array using something like `for` or `foreach`, or `serializing` the array an using `strstr`. But these options don't sound efficient. There is a great post about parsing time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324665/which-is-faster-in-array-or-a-bunch-of-expressions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the elements in the keys:

```
$myarray[$element] = true;
```

Then you can check it with

```
if ($myarray[$element])
```

The lookup in the [hash table](http://nikic.github.com/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html) should be much faster than the search in the array values.