# Print two lists based on two related database tables

Tags: php, loops, join, mysqli, conditional-statements

I have these 2 while loops.

1. Loop. Left side screen. Shows users attached to a task.

   ```
   $getcurrentusers = $conn->prepare("SELECT u.userid, u.username, u.Fname, u.inactive, r.userid, r.job_id FROM users AS u INNER JOIN job_responsible AS r ON u.userid = r.userid WHERE u.inactive = 0 AND r.job_id = $getPostID ORDER BY u.Fname");
   $getcurrentusers->execute();
   $resultgetcurrentusers = $getcurrentusers->get_result();
   $getcurrentusers->close();
   if ($resultgetcurrentusers->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $resultgetcurrentusers->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo $row["username"]." (".$row["Fname"].")<br />";
       }
   } else {
       echo "Der er ikke valgt nogle ansvarlige til denne opgave.";
   }
   ```
2. Loop. Right side screen. List all possible users that can be added to the task

   ```
   $getdepartmentview = $SetDepartmentView;
   $explodegetdepartmentview = explode(",",$getdepartmentview);
   $implodegetdepartmentview = "'".implode("','",$explodegetdepartmentview)."'";
   $getusers = $conn->prepare("SELECT userid, username, Fname, inactive FROM users WHERE departmentid IN ($implodegetdepartmentview) AND inactive = 0 ORDER BY Fname");
   $getusers->execute();
   $resultgetusers = $getusers->get_result();
   $getusers->close();
   if ($resultgetusers->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $resultgetusers->fetch_assoc()) { 
           echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"choose_responsible[]\" value=\"".$row["userid"].",\" />".$row["Fname"]."<br />";
       } 
   }
   ```

The problem is, I would really like, that the input checkbox is 'checked' on the right side when there is a match from the left side 1. loop.

So..

```
Loop 1 | Loop 2
name3  | name1
name5  | name2
name7  | name3 - Inputbox checked
name8  | name4
       | name5 - Inputbox checked
       | name6
       | name7 - Inputbox checked
       | name8 - Inputbox checked
       | name9
       | name10
```

Comment: You could pass the loops into arrays and use [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: Is there a reason that the grouping cannot be done in a single query?  You are not using placeholders in your prepared statements.

Comment: You can grab all of the information that you need with one query.  Just use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN and add your specified `r.job_id` condition part of the ON, not the WHERE.

Comment: I tried LEFT JOIN using only 1 query. Problem was, that it listed the usernames multiple times, cause 1 user could occur inifinite in responsible table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first loop you can store user_id in an array

```
$user_ids[] = $row["userid"]
```

In the second loop you check the current user id if it exists in the previous saved $user_ids array

```
$checked = false;
if (in_array($row["userid"], $user_ids)) {
    $checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Looped calls of `in_array()` probably the worst performer of all comparison techniques.

Comment: A faster way can be to store $user_ids[$row["userid"]] = 1 in the first loop, and check if isset($user_ids[$row["userid"]]) in the second. The OP is learning, I don't think is thinking about performance too much.

Comment: For performance of in_array with large number of iteration you can should refere this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324665/which-is-faster-in-array-or-a-bunch-of-expressions-in-php
But @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4527645/valeriu-ciuca is right, questioner is not thinking about performance.

Answer (score 0):

This task calls for a LEFT JOIN in a single query to avoid multiple trips to the database and to avoid inefficient php processes on the result set.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT u.userid,
       u.username,
       u.Fname,
       u.inactive,
       r.userid responsibleUserId,
       r.job_id
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN job_responsible AS r
    ON u.userid = r.userid
        AND r.job = ?
WHERE u.inactive = 0
ORDER BY u.Fname
SQL;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $getPostID);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Now you have all of the data that you need and therefore no more reasons to visit the database.

To list the users who are assigned to the targeted job, you iterate the array of associative arrays and show users where `job_id` is not null.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user['job_id']) {
        printf('%s (%s)<br />', $user['username'], $user['Fname']);
    }
}
```

To display all users and conditionally check checboxes next to names that are already "responsible", iterate the array again and rely on `job_id` to determine the checkbox.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    printf(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="choose_responsible[]" value="%d"%s/>%s<br />',
        $user['userid'],
        $user['job_id'] ? ' checked' : '',
        $user['Fname']
    );
}
```